# Web Crawler gets slower with time

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am doing a data extraction project where i am required to build a  web scraping program written using python using selenium and phantomjs headless webkit as browser for scaping public information like friendlist in facebook.The program is starting fairly fast but after a day of running it is getting slower and slower and I cannot figure out why ?? Can anyone give me an idea why it is getting slower ? I am running on a local machine which pretty good specs of 4gb ram and quad core processor . Does FB provide any API to find friends of friends ?

Comment: It could be because of your program consuming too much memory space.

Comment: is there a way to check for sure that it is comsuming large memory space  ??

Comment: You should post the code for us to see.

Comment: I have basically used a BFS search

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue. We resolved this by closing browser automatically after particular time interval. Clear temporary cache and open new browser instance and continue the process.

Comment: does quiting a webdriver instance of phantomjs automatically deletes cache content ?

Comment: Its supposed to delete cache, but its an open source software, we can not expect quality all the time. WebDriver's core is browser automation. Rest we have to take care.